# Defining a rule that the user cannot query

Tags: prolog, logtalk

How do I define a rule that the user cannot query?
I only want the program itself to call this rule through another rule.

Ex:

rule1():- rule2().

rule2():- 1<5.

?-rule1().

true

?-rule2().

(I don't know what the answer will be, I just want this query to fail!)

Comment: Which Prolog system are you using?  Why is it so important that the user not call this particular rule (as opposed to just not documenting it)?

Comment: Lets say rule2() updates a value. I only want the value to be updated when you call rule1(). I don't want the user to be able to call rule2 because it will muck everything up.

Comment: Have you tried to use modules?

Comment: @Kaarel: please explain.

Answer (score 5):

Use a Logtalk object to encapsulate your predicates. Only the predicates that you declare public can be called (from outside the object). Prolog modules don't prevent calling any predicate as using explcit qualification bypasses the list of explicitly exported predicates.

A simple example:

```
:- object(rules).

    :- public(rule1/1).
    rule1(X) :-
        rule2(X).

    rule2(X) :-
        X < 5.

:- end_object.
```

After compiling and loading the object above:

```
?- rules::rule1(3).
true.

?- rules::rule2(3).
error(existence_error(predicate_declaration,rule2(3)),rules::rule2(3),user)
```

If you edit the object code and explicitly declare rule2/1 as private you would get instead the error:

```
?- rules::rule2(3).
error(permission_error(access,private_predicate,rule2(3)),rules::rule2(3),user)
```

More information and plenty of examples at http://logtalk.org/

Comment: +1 from me, but could you give a (minimal/trivial) example how to do it? I've never seen/heard about Logtalk

Answer (score 2):

First, some notes:

- I think you mean "predicate" instead of "rule". A predicate is a `name/k` thing such as `help/0` (and `help/1` is another) and can have multiple clauses, among them facts and rules, e.g. `length([], 0).` (a fact) and `length([H|T], L) :- ... .` (a rule) are two clauses of one predicate `length/2`.
- Do not use empty parenthesis for predicates with no arguments – in SWI-Prolog at least, this will not work at all. Just use `predicate2` instead of `predicate2()` in all places.
- If you try to call an undefined predicate, SWI-Prolog will say 
  `ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: predicate2/0 (DWIM could not correct goal)` and Sicstus-Prolog will say 
  `{EXISTENCE ERROR: predicate2: procedure user:predicate2/0 does not exist}`

Now, to the answer. Two ideas come to my mind.

(1) This is a hack, but you could assert the predicate(s) every time you need them and retract them immediately afterwards:

```
predicate1 :- 
      assert(predicate2), predicate2, retractall(predicate2).
```

If you want a body and arguments for `predicate2`, do `assert(predicate2(argument1, argument2) :- (clause1, clause2, clause3))`.

(2) Another way to achieve this would be to introduce an extra argument for the predicate which you do not want to be called by the user and use it for an identification that the user cannot possibly provide, but which you can provide from your calling predicate. This might be a large constant number which looks random, or even a sentence. This even enables you to output a custom error message in case the wrong identification was provided.

Example:

```
 predicate1 :- 
        predicate2("Identification: 2349860293587").

 predicate2(Identification) :- 
        Identification = "Identification: 2349860293587", 
        1 < 5.
 predicate2(Identification) :- Identification \= "Identification: 2349860293587",
        write("Error: this procedure cannot be called by the user. Use predicate1/0 instead."), 
        fail.
```

I don't use the equivalent `predicate2("Identification: 2349860293587")` for the first clause of `predicate2/0`, because I'm not sure where the head of the clause might appear in Prolog messages and you don't want that. I use a `fail` in the end of the second clause just so that Prolog prints `false` instead of `true` after the error message. And finally, I have no idea how to prevent the user from looking up the source code with `listing(predicate2)` so that will still make it possible to simply look up the correct identification code if s/he really wants to. If it's just to keep the user from doing accidental harm, it should however suffice as a protection.

Answer (score 1):

This reminds me to facility found in Java. There one can query the
curent call stack, and use this to regulate permissions of calling
a method. Translated to Prolog we find in the old DEC-10 Prolog the 
following predicate:

ancestors(L)
     Unifies L with a list of ancestor goals for the current clause. 
     The list starts with the parent goal and ends with the most recent 
     ancestor coming from a call in a compiled clause. The list is printed 
     using print and each entry is preceded by the invocation number in 
     parentheses followed by the depth number (as would be given in a 
     trace message). If the invocation does not have a number (this will 
     occur if Debug Mode was not switched on until further into the execution) 
     then this is marked by "-". Not available for compiled code.

Since the top level is usually a compiled predicate prolog/0, this could be
used to write a predicate that inspects its own call stack, and then decides
whether it wants to go into service or not.

```
rule2 :- ancestors(L), length(L,N), N<2, !, write('Don't call me'), fail.
rule2 :- 1<5.
```

In modern Prologs we don't find so often the ancestors/1 predicate anymore.
But it can be simulated along the following lines. Just throw an error, and 
in case that the error is adorned with a stack trace, you get all you need:

```
ancestors(L) :- catch(sys_throw_error(ignore),error(ignore,L),true).
```

But beware stack eliminiation optimization might reduce the stack and thus
the list returned by ancestors/1.

Best Regards

P.S.: Stack elimination optimization is already explained here:
[4]     Warren, D.H.D. (1983): An Abstract Prolog Instruction Set, Technical Note 309, SRI International, October, 1983

A discussion for Jekejeke Prolog is found here:
http://www.jekejeke.ch/idatab/doclet/prod/en/docs/10_pro08/13_press/03_bench/05_optimizations/03_stack.html